# Three different PHP versions?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm new to php and haven't programmed in years. I'm trying to install and debug a small php page on Mac Catalina.

Whilst installing XDebug, I've noticed that:

1. /usr/local/etc/php contains only 7.2 folder
2. `php -v` returns 7.3.11
3. phpinfo() tells me that version is 7.4

I'm totally lost. My ultimate goal is to debug using VS Code.

Thanks

Comment: `php -v` will tell you the version of php **cli** (the one used when you call php code in the console). `phpinfo()` will tell you the version of php **cgi** (the one used for web server)

Comment: thanks, this explains a lot. I can't find the php.ini for either cli or cgi versions - any idea where it should be?

Comment: If I read the phpinfo output before asking, I'd save people's time ... found it. Thanks :)